# Raspberry Pi, C #, Mono, SignalR, the connection crashes after I set the time

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, mono, signalr, raspbian

I have easy app based on C#, SignalR, OWIN and Katana, which run with help of Mono on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian).
The app works normally into moment, until I set system time in Raspbian (for example with  **date** command ) and time is bigger than time, which was in system to this moment.
If I set smaller time, all is ok, but if I set bigger time, connection between the client (web app) and the server (mono app) crashes and I must restart entire application.
Does anyone have  some idea?

Comment: What do you mean "bigger time" and "smaller time"? You mean when you increase the date (towards the future) or decrease the date (into the past)?

Comment: I'm sorry for my english.
Let's tell, that system time is March 30, 2018, 10.00 AM.
If I set in this moment at console "date 033009592018", the app will works, if I set  "date 033010012018", app crashes.

Comment: It might help to help if you tell us about what the app des. Does it use the time?

Comment: Yes, final app must use time, however I made easy test app and with its help I demonstrate this problem. My english is very weak and I made short video for these purposes. Video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUyvvE3KRaA)

Comment: SignalR has a number of timeouts measured in seconds. I guess that if you change the time to be more in the future the time between the "new" now and the previously recorded time is bigger than one of these timeouts and the connection is terminated.